# Placing TextView in grid in different resolutions

Tags: android, android-layout

I need to make an `Activity` in Android that has a grid (20x8) drawn in the background with cells of different styles. I have 3 background images for the 3 ldpi-mdpi-hdpi resolutions.

The problem is that I need to place a `TextView` in every cell but if I put it in an absolute position for a resolution (eg. ldpi) it is not in the right position for mdpi and hdpi.

Which is the Android approach to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

I would use a `GridView` so I can specify the layout for every item inside.
Check this tutorial: [Hello, GridView](http://developer.android.com/guide/tutorials/views/hello-gridview.html).

Comment: Sorry, i don't understand how to do it: i have to build a grid but it has cols and rows of different sizes and i need to have a background image over which i have to build text: how can it be done with the GridView? Seeing the examples it seems that the cells have all the same size